# How to fetch scrollable content using appium and wdio

Tags: android, appium, android-uiautomator, wdio

I'm using Appium with WDIO. I'm automating an Android native app page, where the goal is the fetch all the details in the different sections of the page. I know that the Appium with UiAutomator2 only fetches the details of the elements in the visible part of the screen, how to properly scroll and fetch all the details?

Thanks in Advance